# How can I make a folder share survive a dismount in Vista? (for use to backup to Truecrypt volumes)

Tags: network-shares, mount, truecrypt

It is well documented that Vista's backup utility cannot recognise Truecrypt volumes as viable destinations for backup. The known workaround for this is to backup to a ***folder*** within the TrueCrypt volume by ***sharing*** it and making Vista access it as a network share.

However, every time after the TrueCrypt volume dismounts (after every reboot), I find myself needing to manually re-share the folder in question before backup can find it again.

Is there a way to make the share survive these dismounts?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. I remember I solved this problem with a different method: rather than sharing as a network drive, I ran TrueCrypt itself as the `SYSTEM` user (using `psexec -s -i TrueCrypt.exe`, [`psexec` available here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), must be 'run as administrator'). Additionally, I mounted the drives as removable media, to work around a VSS error. But that was on a Server 2003 machine, so YMMV.

Comment: @Bob HA! I was just about to post this as a possible solution, psexec is awesome isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't use truecrypt's automount function to automatically mount the folder at startup? Truecrypt would need to be installed on the Vista box but you should be able to get the same drive letter if you pick a letter like x: y: or z: that'll probably never get reassigned.

Comment: I can, but the problem is that even if I get TC to mount the drive volume at startup, the folder inside it is no longer shared. I need to re-share it

Comment: @OldSchool Can you post the documentation on this Vista limitation? I don't understand because once the drive is mounted, the encryption is (*should be*) transparent to Vista as just another drive, so I'm curious to see the problems.

Comment: This is a good post (there are many others here and on the web at large) explaining the issue http://superuser.com/questions/126111/how-can-you-use-windows-backup-with-a-truecrypt-encrypted-backup-destination/126112#126112  However the problem I post about is about making a share survive a dismount and not just about Truecrypt

Comment: @OldSchool you should try Bob's solution of using psexec to mount the truecrypt volume using the system account, that should solve your problem.