# Create incremental/complete backups from a fully encrypted disk using using TrueCrypt?

Tags: security, backup, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption

I have a tricky question about whole disk encryption with TrueCrypt for which I have never found a clear answer:

**What method do you  recommend/use for create backups from a whole disk encrypted disk with TrueCrypt to an external device?**.

I would really love to get my System & Data partitions (C and D) automatically backed up to an external hard disk (complete initial backup + incremental backups would be perfect). TrueCrypt whole disk encryption (like the other whole disk encryption software I suppose) is a real pain for that kind of task, and I never found a way to reach that goal.

My ideal goal would be backup the system partition once a week and all the data partition content *automatically* to an external usb drive every day by syncing the modified/created files (incremental backups would be awesome). The thing is that there is a lot of software to accomplish this task (Cobian backup, Acronis...) but It appears doesn't work well with the mounted TrueCrypt volume/disk.

I just found a "simple" way to get a complete backup but it is a bit uncomfortable solution [Here](http://roman.st/Article/Mixing-TrueCrypt-whole-disk-encryption-Acronis-True-Image-Home-backups).

Also, the backup and restore feature built into Windows 7 is not a confortable solution to work with. That was discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/126111/how-can-you-use-windows-backup-with-a-truecrypt-encrypted-backup-destination).

### Additional Info

- **Operating System:** Windows 7 Professional 64bits
- **TrueCrypt version:** 7.1a

Comment: what is your goal? - backup your data/files or a complete disk/partition-image?

Comment: Can't you just mount it and then backup the plaintext volume like any other volume?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy My ideal goal would be backup the system partition once a week and all the data partition content **automatically** to an external usb drive every day by syncing the modified/created files (**incremental** backups would be right). The thing is that there is a lot of software to accomplish this task (Cobian backup, Acronis...) but It appears doesn't work well with the mounted TrueCrypt volume/disk.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, I can. But is very meshy because you have to copy and paste/overrite the data and if you modify the name of just one single file... you'll have the same data duplicated with different names. Not to mention of Eclipse/VS project folders... It would be a mesh and a bit elegant...  I am interesting in something smart like incremental/differencial backups complatible with the TrueCrypt mounted disk.

Comment: Updated post. Added more concrete info about my goal here :D.