# Can I use Dropbox or SpiderOak with a whole disk encrypted system using TrueCrypt with no problems?

Tags: dropbox, truecrypt, disk-encryption

A bit silly question right here...

**Is it possible to use Dropbox or SpiderOak with a whole disk encrypted system using TrueCrypt whithout any problem syncing ?**

- Can these applications recognize the disk mounted by TrueCrypt?
- The data/folder will be recognized and treated as plain/normal data if you share them with others through those applications.

I am not talking about TrueCrypt containers but whole disk encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When the software is running and the system is on/logged in the disk has already applied its encryption keys and the data is readable. When using full disk encryption a system learns how to 'decrypt' the drive during the boot process - if things go wrong nothing can be read and the system can't boot to the OS on the drive. When the system is online the data is seen 'through' the decryption process and is thus readable. Were the drive to be taken or put in other hardware the disk would be gibberish without the key.

If you're running Dropbox or something like that, that process only ever sees the unencrypted form of the data (just like you do) and, because of that, it  can back it up just fine. If you think about it, you don't need to find a file, input a decryption key, and then load the newly decrypted file to read it; it's already done because that process was done during system boot.

Comment: wow, that was a quick reply . Yes, that's just what I thought but I wasn't sure and i wanted to confirm before doing all the encryption. I really appreciate your reply  ;).

Comment: Also, I had my doubts about this because the backup feature built into Windows 7 doesn't recognize the volume mounted by TrueCrypt but yeah this is a different thing because Dropbox doesn't run as SYSTEM and can read the volume (mounted for the current user account). It has sense. 

In fact, this is related to another unanswered question I asked: https://superuser.com/questions/932990/create-incremental-complete-backups-from-a-fully-encrypted-disk-using-using-true

Comment: So, the way that 'full disk' encryption works is that when the system is running (after the MBR stuff is done) is described pretty well here: "since disk encryption generally uses the same key for encrypting the whole volume, all data is decryptable when the system runs." This means that as soon as 'Windows' start screen is up and running, the data is 'readable' by anything on the system because it successfully used it's decryption key during the boot process (otherwise the system couldn't read the data and thus couldn't boot). So as long as the system starts, data can be read on that system

Comment: Thanks again for your full reply ;). I was looking for a second opinion to be sure. I already knew that TrueCrypt uses its own driver to load its own bootcode into MBR but I wasn't sure about the part with the encryption at session time. 

*PS. I marked your answer as useful but I still haven't 15 rep points so it does't appear reflected (still) ;)*

Comment: No worries! Glad to help :)